# "out of court" alternative meaning in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, synonyms

Is there any alternative meaning of "out of court" than the one we knoe linked with real life court situations. The sentence which I sense it should mean something else is as follows:

> However, its real purpose is not to encourage controversy but to draw
>   the committed student of true philosophy away from this discussion
>   altogether, to leave out of court matters of opinion and belief, and
>   to move on to the more serious concerns which can be treated according
>   to the principles of demonstrations and hence of philosophy proper.

quoted from the 21st page of the following article:

https://www.jstor.org/stable/1595834?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: The first question to answer is whether 'out of court' attaches to 'leave' or 'matters'.

Comment: Here "out of court" means : *too unimportant for consideration*. http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/out-of-court - ... *out of court* matters of opinion and belief,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to *leave out of court* matters of opinion and belief

means

> to *set aside, as irrelevant*, matters of opinion and belief